# Compare persons(objects) from List by adress if live more people on same address count it

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

I making program which adds people (name, address, age) to a LinkedList and comparing  addresses, unique address ad to a key into HashMap and how many people live on this address add to value into HashMap;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Creating 10 persons name, address, years
    Osoba osoba1 = new Osoba("Nikola", "Nemanjina 6", 23);
    Osoba osoba2 = new Osoba("Marko", "Nemanjina 6", 23);
    Osoba osoba3 = new Osoba("Vuk", "Nemanjina 6", 23);
    Osoba osoba4 = new Osoba("Milos", "Profesora Vasica 1/a", 23);
    Osoba osoba5 = new Osoba("Jovan", "Profesora Vasica 1/a", 23);
    Osoba osoba6 = new Osoba("Goran", "Profesora Vasica 1/a", 23);
    Osoba osoba7 = new Osoba("Milan", "Profesora Vasica 1/a", 23);
    Osoba osoba8 = new Osoba("Zarko", "Profesora Vasica 1/a", 23);
    Osoba osoba9 = new Osoba("Djordje", "Nemanjina 6", 23);
    Osoba osoba10 = new Osoba("Pero", "Terazije 12", 23);

    //Adding persons to a List osobe
    List<Osoba> osobe = new LinkedList<>();
    osobe.add(osoba1);
    osobe.add(osoba2);
    osobe.add(osoba3);
    osobe.add(osoba4);
    osobe.add(osoba5);
    osobe.add(osoba6);
    osobe.add(osoba7);
    osobe.add(osoba8);
    osobe.add(osoba9);
    osobe.add(osoba10);

    Map<String, Integer> personsMap = new HashMap<>();

}
```

Comment: Ok, that's cool. It seems that you have no question, so this case is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Java 8's streams make this pretty easy:

```
Map<String, Long> personsMap =
    osobe.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupBy(Osoba::getAddress, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Its difficult to me to understand this function;

Answer (score 0):

What Mureinik said is simpler and will work, another more "deployed" (if you are a beginner) solution is something like this:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

       String[] str = {"Two", "Three", "Two", "Five", "Two"};
       Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(str[i]))
                map.put(str[i], map.get(str[i]) + 1);
            else
                map.put(str[i], 1);
        }

        System.out.println(map);

    }
}
```